# Set single region not selectable

Tags: jquery, maps, jvectormap

I have an array filled with the regions that are on the map

```
var regions = [
    {name: 'BE-WV', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-OV', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-AN', positions: false},
    {name: 'BE-LI', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-VB', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-BR', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-WB', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-HG', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-NA', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-LK', positions: true},
    {name: 'BE-LX', positions: true},
];
```

And I was wondering if it is possible to create a function that checks the regions. If that region has a position:true it should be selectable, otherwise it shouldn't.

I already created a function which changes the mouse cursor on hover if it should be selectable or not.

```
onRegionOver: function(event, code, region){
    for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        element = regions[i];
        elementName = element['name'];
    if ( elementName == code){
        if (element['positions'] !== false){
         document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
         }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's quite a hacky one.
In the onRegionClick function, check if the clicked region has a false position.

Then paste this code inside the if

```
 var m = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
 m.series.regions[0].elements[code].element.style.selected.fill = 'grey';
```

where grey is the color of unselected regions.